# How do I properly check for null on nullable infix receivers?

Tags: kotlin, infix-notation

I have a Kotlin infix function stubbed out thusly:

```
private fun statementMeetsConditions(policy: PolicyStatement, per: PolicyEnforcementRequest): Boolean {
    return policy.conditions areMetBy per.attributes
}

private infix fun JsonNode?.areMetBy(attributes: Map<String, String>): Boolean {
    if (this == null) return true //no conditions, so we pass

    TODO("Condition-based policies not implemented")
}
```

At runtime, `policy.conditions` is null.

[image]

I would have thought that `(this == null)` would evaluate to true, however I am triggering a runtime exception as the infix function hits the `TODO`.

These are both member functions on a class -- so I suspect that "this" is evaluating to the instance of the class (*not* null), rather than the `JsonNode?` I was expecting. How can I ensure that I'm referencing the `JsonNode?` instead of the class?

Comment: I think you have another problem here... checking whether `this` is `null` works on `infix` functions the way you would expect, even if those extension functions are wrapped in a class. So my guess is, that your `JsonNode` is probably not `null`.

Comment: how about testing with `this ?. run { .. } ?: run { .. }` making sure it's really `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullNode` ([jackson-databind-javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/NullNode.html)) is not `null` ;-) `NullNode` is actually its own type... So you may rather want to check against that type instead...

Checking whether `this` is `null` works on `infix` functions the way you would expect, even if those extension functions are wrapped in a class.

So to check whether your `policy.conditions` contains that `NullNode` you may rather change the condition to the following instead:

```
if (this is NullNode) return true
```

Comment: I came to this conclusion myself after more minutes testing. You beat me to posting a self-answer however, so the checkmark is yours!

Comment: @Roland correct +1, funny thing is "null" actually comes from toString() :D see my answer

Answer (score 0):

That null check is good as is, you're correct that it checks the nullable `JsonNode?` receiver in this case.

However, the [`TODO`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) method in Kotlin is an explosive todo, as in it always throws a `NotImplementedException` when it's hit. This is why this code is allowed to compile, even though not all branches return a `Boolean` value from the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a little tricky. Note how conditions value is `"null"` rather than `null`. This is because

`toString()` of `ValueNode` calls `asText()` of `NullNode` which returns a `String` of value "null", so the receiver `JsonNode?` actually was not null all along.

So, as Roland already stated, you have to check whether the receiver is of type `NullNode`.